# Why do pages of a book oscillate when kept under fan?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, flow, oscillators, fan

I have noticed that when one of my book is kept under a ceiling fan, its pages keep on moving up and down due to the wind of the fan. Why don't they just settle in equilibrium ? What causes them to keep moving up and down? also the period of this motion is pretty random and doesn't match with the period of rotation of fan at all. Unlike other oscillating systems they don't even have any elastic energy or any other force I could think of that sort

Answer (score 1):

A likely guess is [vortex shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_shedding): the air is moving in such a way that a vortex forms first on one side, then on the other side, producing an unsteady oscillatory flow. Things are doubtless more complex since the pages respond to the pressure changes, changing the boundary a bit. I can easily imagine that you can get proper chaotic oscillations in such a system.

The vortex shedding frequency depends on the air velocity $v$ like $f \approx v \text{St}/D$ where $\text{St}$ is the [Strouhal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strouhal_number) $\approx 0.2$ and $D$ the size of the obstacle. It shows that the frequency can be independent of the fan period (a good fan produces an even flow; a bad fan may add pulsatile flow that complicates the dynamics even more, of course).